# when I send "154" value from adapter to fragment, why I get boolean value?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

when I send "154" value from adapter to fragment, why I get boolean value?

my code in adapter

```
holder.coin_DiamondImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CoinDiamondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fid", newFeedModels.get(position).getFeedID());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

and in the fragment code

```
private String fid;
fid = getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("fid");
```

why I need to change to private boolean fid;?

Comment: use get String extra instaed

Comment: okay, thx bro. ..

Comment: here is how it should look:
`priivate String fib;
Intent intent = getIntent();
fib = intent.getStringExtra("String");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why I need to change to private boolean fid;?

You don't need to. You have to ask for a String resource instead of checking for existence. So, change this line:

```
private String fid;
fid = getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("fid");
```

To:

```
private String fid;
fid = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("fid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `hasExtra()` returns boolean value. Instead of `hasExtra("fid")` use `getStringExtra("fid")` which will return a String value

**Change**

```
fid = getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("fid");
```

**To**

```
fid = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("fid");
```